# Setting UIITextView border color

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to set the silver color for my UITextView border. I tried this:

```
theGroupTextLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3.5f;
    theGroupTextLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

...but in the color option there are only some colors like whiteColor, BlackColor, Green...

What if I want silver?

Comment: I doubt if there is an exact "Silver" color. It is more of a texture than a simple color. You might have to try with an image to get that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just need to customize your color with RGB values because what you are seeing are just a handful of predefined colors for your convenience. This is an example of a custom color with RGB values.

```
[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.2f blue:0.7f alpha:1.0f] CGColor]; // Not actually silver
```

NOTE: Normally you will find a number between 0 and 255 for each value but this function takes floats so just take those number and divide it by 255 to get the float value of what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use RGB values for custom colors;

```
CGFloat nRed=128.0/255.0;
CGFloat nBlue=98.0/255.0;
CGFloat nGreen=53.0/255.0;
UIColor *myColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:nRed green:nBlue blue:nGreen alpha:1];
```

[Choose RGB Values Here](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm)

Something around R:193 G:205 B:205 would be close to silver

Answer (score 1):

Try to set you your color like this

```
theGroupTextLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3.5f;
theGroupTextLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:(RedRGB.0/255.0) 
                                                       green:(GreenRGB.0/255.0) 
                                                        blue:(BlueRGB.0/255.0) 
                                                       alpha:(AlphaRGB.0/255.0)] CGColor];
```

Comment: for some reason what ever values I put the border is always black

Comment: if I remove the /255 on each value instead the border is white

Comment: This is really nasty. Obviously those RedRGB etc. are defines that are set towards integer values. Ugly and prone to error.

Comment: Till, are you saying that the answer above is not correct and I sould not use it?

Comment: AlphaRGB is just the opacity of your color

Comment: @Alessandro Well it will work if you use `define`s but using those in 99.9% of all cases is wrong and bad style.

Comment: @Alessandro we put the /255 because the rgb color is from 0-255 so when you put your color value it will be like this (124.0/255.0)

Comment: also do not forget to add the DOT ZERO (124.0/255.0)

Comment: just for testing try theGroupTextLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.6   green:0.45   blue:0.76  alpha:0.9] CGColor];

Comment: the color valus should be between 0-1